# How to prevent signature input double spending

Tags: solidity

Let's say I have implemented a contract that allows you to transfer a token to a recipient for whom you do not have the address.

Let's say I have 5 of token x and I want to give 1 to my friend and I do not know her address, as a result I send her a message (e.g. give one token from my account to anyone who claims this) and a corresponding signature.

My friend can then broadcast the function call claimToken(message, signature) and get the token from me in the smart contract.

My question is: how do I prevent a node from seeing this transaction in the mempool and taking the inputs (message, signature) and sending the transaction with a higher fee, essentially getting confirmed before my friend and taking the token for themselves?

I understand that this is solved if you sign the message with the recipients address, but this cannot happen when you do not know the address of the recipient.

Comment: I think the keywords for this topic are "contract vulnerabilities"

Answer (score 1):

You can have the recipient self-sign if your contract can be designed to support that.

Let `E'(E(m, k), k') = m` where `E` is an asymmetric encryption algorithm and `E'` is its inverse, `m` is a message, and `k'` is a public key and `k` is a private key; WLOG, `E` could be `E'`. Let S be the sender and R be the recipient of the token; let `R` be R's Ethereum account.

I believe the following scheme is not vulnerable to the out-spending attack:

1. S securely sends `k` to R.
2. R computes `m' = E(R, k)` and calls `claimToken(m')`.
3. In `claimToken`, the function allows claiming of tokens if and only if `E(m', k') == R`.

This, by itself, does not prevent R from reusing `k` to claim the token multiple times. If you wanted to have, say, five claimable sets of tokens, you could do something like this:

1. S securely sends `k_i` to R where `k_i` is the *i*th private key (corresponding to *k'*_i).
2. R computes `m' = E(R, k_i)` and calls `claimToken(m', i)`.
3. In `claimToken`, the function allows claiming of tokens if and only if `E(m', k_i') == R` AND `used[i]` is false.
4. The `claimToken` function then sets `used[i]` to true.

This requires the public keys to be pre-programmed into the contract. You could alternately have an arbitrary number of keys by having the owner of the contract or a delegate update the verifying public key to a new value each time tokens are claimed and only allowing `claimToken` to succeed if the public key has not been previously successfully used to claim tokens.

Comment: Hi Lungj, thanks for your answer however it does not solve the problem because you have to know the recipients pubkey. If we knew that we could simply sign a message including the address of the recipient and prevent theft.

Comment: @James not sure which step I posted involves S knowing R’s public key.